# Using percentiles instead of mean for the parameter of the response variable in regression

Tags: regression, sas

I want to do a linear regression in SAS between two variables. What I would get is the parameter for the mean of my response variable (and the 95% confidence interval for the parameter), but that is not what I want.

For example: If Predictor=3, Response=13, prediction interval between 10 and 16

What I want to know is what is the response for a percentile, 80% to be precise, of the cases are and the prediction interval for that percentile.

For example, If Predictor=3, 80% of responses will be below between 14 and 15

I should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to know the percentiles for the predicted value $\hat{y}$ or for the coefficient itself $\beta$?

Comment: I want to know the predicted interval between which 80% of the predicted values will fall below of.

Comment: So you want to know what value it is where 80% of the predicted values are below this value and 20% are above it? You could always save the predicted values and then figure out where the 80th percentile is. Why are you interested in doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "save the predicted values"? For a given predictor, I would only a single predicted value or at best a prediction interval, no?

Comment: I'm not interested in knowing the mean value for the predicted value. I want to know for any given predictor, on average and the interval, where the cut off point for the Pareto principle is.

Comment: You might be asking about how to perform *quantile regression,* but it is difficult to tell because phrases like "responses for a percentile","  "below between," "on average and on the interval," and "cutoff for the Pareto principle" don't make much sense, at least not without explanation.  Could you make your language a little clearer?

Comment: you might want to look at quantile regression, ie proc quantreg in sas: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/213-30.pdf

Comment: English isn't my native langage, but I'll do my best to make things a bit clearer. For example, if we estimate the mean (or a interval for the mean) for a normal distribution, we can assume that 50% of the responses will be below that value. I'm not a fan of given a single value, because it doesn't give a magnitude, so I prefer always an interval (so the "below between" is to take into account that is not below a value, but below a value that falls it that interval). What I would like is the 80% (hence the Pareto principle 80-20). I hope it's clearer.